# How to manage an AntDesign Tree with React Query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, antd, react-query

I am trying to create an asynchronous editable tree with And Design and I want to use React Query for data management, since it will make managing different branches of the tree querying data from different sources much easier.

Sadly Ant Design has very bad support for HOCs, making it impossible to wrap a TreeNode with a custom component that would manage it's children via a useQuery hook.

As a result since I cannot dynamicaly add hooks based on new nodes being expanded, I would like to ask if there are already common practices or solutions for these kinds of situations, where we need to add more data sources (more hooks), but can't create new components to store them in.

Comment: Would using `useQueries` instead of `useQuery` be of any help? It allow for having a dynamic number of queries without breaking the rules of hooks.

Comment: Yup, that's what I ended up doing, but it's far from a clean solution, since the tree has hierarchical data and useQueries is an array. I ultimately had to add a transformation function between the retrieved data and the tree nodes to rebuild the tree from scratch every time new data is retrieved.

Comment: Going into completely different direction, does the logic have to be on the frontend? Is it imaginable to have a BFF architecture where the client side JS only has to call one EP with data and the BFF resolves it all?

Comment: Sadly, it does in my particular case, but either way creating a BFF or creating the aforementioned front-end setup are both undesirable levels of extra complexity compared to having react-query manage each of the node's children via a separate hook, but that's not achievable without HOCs.